# What is the lifetime of local struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I have following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


struct M {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    ~M(){}
};

std::vector<M> ms;

void met(int i)
{
    // This struct 'm' does not get deleted after lifetime of function "met" is over  
    M m;
    m.a = i;
    m.b = i * i;
    ms.push_back(m);
}


int main()
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   met(i);
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  std::cout << ms[i].a << " : " << ms[i].b << std::endl;
 }
 return 0;
}

// OUTPUT
0 : 0
1 : 1
2 : 4
3 : 9
4 : 16
5 : 25
6 : 36
7 : 49
8 : 64
9 : 81
```

As we know scope of local variable is lifetime of immediate code block. In above code, scope of `struct M` is lifetime `function met`. But in above code works fine as we can see output given below code. I was expecting undefined behavior Cause `M m` has to be deleted once function met return to main.  Is is anything special about struct in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: I think you need to read up on how `std::vector` works.

Comment: You're storing instances of `M` by value not referencing by pointer.

Comment: Sorry wrong close reason! The answer simply is, that `std::vector<T>::push_back()` takes a copy of `T`, not a reference.

Comment: i was expecting undefined behavior but it clearly show working fine. i  am calling it for 10 time and all call stack cant get allocated sequentially...

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ thanks thats looks logical to me

Comment: You seem to be confused about the difference between *types*, *variables* and *objects*. They're all different things.

Comment: @twid: "I was expecting undefined behavior" - then you don't know how `vector` and copy-construction work in general.

Comment: @Remy: I know that just failed to notice `std::vector::push_back()` works on copy and not reference

Answer (score 4):

The structs in met() are, in fact, deleted. The ones in the vector are copies, made when push_back() is called.

Answer (score 2):

> // This struct 'm' does not get deleted after lifetime of function "met" is over

Yes, it does.  What you are not taking into account is that you are putting a **copy** of `m` inside of the `vector`, and your struct has a compiler-generated copy constructor to make a copy of the member values.  `m` is gone when `met()` exits, but the `vector` is still alive since it has global scope, and you are outputting what is stored in the `vector` before it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

When you store the instance variable `m` into the vector, that actual instance is not stored. What happens is this:

1. Create the struct `m` and change its properties.
2. Call the **copy constructor** of `m`. This is a special constructor method which is used whenever an implicit copy is requested.
3. Put this copy into the vector.
4. Delete the original value `m` as the function ends.

By default, the compiler creates a copy constructor for every struct. The default implementation is just to (shallow-)copy each member variable one-by-one. Because your member variables are just `int`s, they are copied over to the newly copied variable inside the vector.

This needs to be kept in mind when you have bigger structures, as the entire structure can be copied around multiple times implicitly.